# Using Multiple API results from DB to populate a table, why are my results duplicating rather than appending properly?

Tags: javascript, express, axios, sequelize.js

## JS code

**Im calling the case information in the first function to get the name of the Contact and Site, as they exists in separate model. Case and caseDetail are associated through multiple factors, however for UI purposes, Id like to display the actual names of each rather than just the ID that associates the information.
 
I believe my other chance at a solution is combining the two models so all the information exists on one call, allowing my looped results to have all the proper information.
Screen Shot of table** [returnedResults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9hNs.png)

```
        //    $tbody.empty(); 
            await axios.get('/api/Case').then((response) => {
                response.data.forEach((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    const caseContactName = response.Contact.name;
                    const caseSiteName = response.Site.siteName;
                    callRmaInvent(caseContactName, caseSiteName)
    
                })
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
            
        }

        const callRmaInvent = async (caseContactName, caseSiteName) => {

        console.log(caseSiteName, caseContactName);
       await axios.get('/api/caseDetail').then((items) => {
        $tbody.empty();
        console.log(items);
        console.log('inventory will go here');
        items.data.forEach((item) => {
            const id = item.id;
            // Table data
            const caseName = item.Case.caseName;
            const caseSite = caseSiteName;
            const caseContact = caseContactName;
            const itemType = item.Part.partType;
            const serialNumber = item.Part.serialNumber;
            const createdAt = item.createdAt;
            const updatedAt = item.updatedAt;
            const faultReason = item.Fault.reasonForReturn;
            const dispositionAction = item.Disposition.actionTaken;
            const addedToInvent = dateFns.format(createdAt, 'MMM D, YY')
            const updatedInvent = dateFns.format(updatedAt, 'MMM D, YY')

            $tbody.append(`
            <tr>
            <td>${id}</td>
            <td>${caseName}</td>
            <td>${caseSite}</td>
            <td>${caseContact}</td>
            <td>${serialNumber}</td>
            <td>${itemType}</td>         
            <td>${faultReason}</td>
            <td>${dispositionAction}</td>
            <td>${addedToInvent}</td>
            <td>${updatedInvent}</td>
            </tr>`)
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });   
    };
$(document).on('click', '#viewDatabase', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    callRmaInvent();
    callRmaCases();
})
```

## Example of Console log to see it is pulling the right information per call

```
script.js:37 Disney World Blake Thompson
script.js:37 Warehouse Eric
```

Comment: You're running an async function in a forEach callback. Which means the promises essentially start all at the same time, then finish in an arbitrary order. You'll probably want to use `Promise.all` here.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I'll give it a shot. Appreciate the feedback!